# How to uninstall the vi text editor preinstalled in Ubuntu?

Tags: vi

I would like to uninstall the vi text editor which is pre-installed in Ubuntu. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to remove vim-tiny in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove vim.tiny
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Comment: instead of hyphen use dot

Comment: When I do this on Ubuntu 16.04, it also wants to remove `ubuntu-minimal`, which seems like a bad idea?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066154/what-is-the-ubuntu-minimal-package-and-do-i-need-it for advice on whether it is safe to remove `ubuntu-minimal`.