# What is the ubuntu-minimal package and do I need it?

Tags: uninstall, vim, ubuntu-minimal

I want to uninstall vim, and according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418601/how-to-uninstall-the-vi-text-editor-preinstalled-in-ubuntu) that is done by uninstalling `vim.tiny`. But when I run `apt remove vim.tiny` apt also wants to remove `ubuntu-minimal`.

What is ubuntu-minimal? Will removing it affect any other program than the vi editor?

Comment: Don't uninstall `ubuntu-minimal`! It's a meta-package which holds almost all dependencies to run Ubuntu. See for yourself: `sudo apt remove ubuntu-minimal --dry-run`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[*ubuntu-minimal*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-minimal) is a *metapackage*.

Here's partial output of the `apt show command`:

```
apt show ubuntu-minimal        
Package: ubuntu-minimal
Version: 1.417
Priority: important
Section: metapackages
Source: ubuntu-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 48.1 kB
Depends: adduser, apt, apt-utils, bzip2, console-setup, debconf, debconf-i18n, eject, init, initramfs-tools, iproute2, iputils-ping, isc-dhcp-client, kbd, kmod, less, locales, lsb-release, mawk, mount, netbase, netcat-openbsd, nplan, passwd, procps, python3, sensible-utils, sudo, tzdata, ubuntu-advantage-tools, ubuntu-keyring, udev, vim-tiny, whiptail
Recommends: rsyslog
```

A metapackage is a list of software that specifies what is installed on your system *during* the initial installation process and when you upgrade from one version of your OS to another. See [What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21497/what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage) for example.

Removing a *metapackage* is otherwise harmless.

While you maybe able to remove *vim-tiny*, the benefits would be negligible and somewhere down the line some other software you install may pull it back in.

Comment: This answers the question I asked. I wish it answered the question of how I remove vim. But I can't ask that, because somebody else already did. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

As explained earlier, 'ubuntu-minimal' is meta package.  It 'requires' the installation of a bunch of other packages which the powers that be consider essential to the smooth operation of a minimal Ubuntu installation.

Removing it has no impact on currently installed packages.  Removing it WILL prevent the future automatic installation of any other package deemed (in their opinion) essential.  [ The package 'ubuntu-advantage-tools' comes to mind. ]

So: Yes, you can remove 'vim.tiny' and 'ubuntu-minimal' with no ill effects, subject to the above caveat.

But when you do, use a dry-run ( 'apt -s ...' ) first and check the output to ensure you are only removing the package(s) you really want to remove...