# removing netplan to use systemd-networkd directly

Tags: systemd-networkd

I want to configure networking using bare systemd-networkd. Instructions are here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_a_static_IP

I haven't used NetworkManager for years, so I'm halfway there but I suspect that to do it correctly I need to bypass the system startup call to netplan. Ideally I can disable it, but I don't know how to do that. There is a lot of information about returning to ifupdown but I don't see much for what I'm looking for.

https://renediepstraten.nl/?p=51 suggests using apt to remove netplan which is too heavy-handed for my liking particularly when `apt remove netplan.io` wants to remove `ubuntu-minimal`.

**Update**
`ubuntu-minimal` can be safely removed. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066154/what-is-the-ubuntu-minimal-package-and-do-i-need-it#:~:text=As%20explained%20earlier%2C%20'ubuntu%2D,impact%20on%20currently%20installed%20packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066154/what-is-the-ubuntu-minimal-package-and-do-i-need-it#:%7E:text=As%20explained%20earlier%2C%20%27ubuntu%2D,impact%20on%20currently%20installed%20packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have a DHCP.

Remove netplan.io

```
sudo apt remove --purge netplan.io
```

Now restart. After restart your pc will have no internet.

Run

```
sudo systemctl disable network-manager
sudo systemctl stop network-manager
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

sudo tee /etc/systemd/network/20-dhcp.network << END
[Match]
Name=enp5s0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
END
```

What the last command doing is, it is appending lines in `/etc/systemd/network/20-dhcp.network`. To know what value you should use in `Name=enp5s0`, run `ip -c link` to get the name of the NIC.

If you do not have DHCP and need to use static IP, Replace

```
[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

with your details (**do not copy paste**, you have to know your IP Address, Gateway and DNS).

```
[Network]
Address=10.1.10.9/24
Gateway=10.1.10.1
DNS=10.1.10.1
```

If you are using wifi, you might have to add the line `IgnoreCarrierLoss=3s` under `[Network]`

Now Run

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Hopefully, you will get back your internet.

Read [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#Required_services_and_setup) for more details , for example if you have both Wired and wireless adapters etc.

Answer (score 1):

To remove `netplan.io` and keeping its dependency `ubuntu-minimal` use:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends netplan.io
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out though that removing ubuntu-minimal has no effect on an installed system. Its purpose is to point to packages required of a minimal install.